# move profile folder to sdcard firefox mobile 14.0

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, blob, indexeddb

I'm coding a mobile web application to do a survey. The web
    application contain a set of audio file. I want to store all the
    audio file in the indexedDB as a blob.

By default, Firefox mobile 14.0 for android store the profile folder in the internal memory which is too small. And when I move the data of Firefox to the SD card, the profile folder doesn't move.

The profile folder contain the indexedDB folder where we store all indexedDB bases.
So what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe storing the audio files as normal files with URLs and making sure that they are properly cached using a [cache manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5) would be a better idea.

See:

- [A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) on HTML5 Rocks
- [Go offline with application cache](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/) on HTML5 Doctor
- [HTML5 Application Cache](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_app_cache.asp) on W3Schools

Comment: thank's but it is the same problem when i want to store the application as offline because the offline cache folder is on the profile folder whos is still on the internal memory